# JQuery DataTables - fnDrawCallback function is executed multiple times

Tags: datatables

Each row of my DataTable is a product, and in each row there is form which adds product to basket when submitted. I thought it would be more elegant if I do that without page refresh. I've added a function to fnDrawCallback, but it is being executed multiple times  - as many times as this table row is being redrawn (filtering, coming back to the same table page).

Php:

```
  <td class="add-to-basket-form"  id="<?php echo str_replace('/', '', $productPartCode); ?>">
    <p class="product-description-mobile visible-xs"><?php echo $productDescription; ?></p>
    <p class="product-partcode-mobile visible-xs"><?php echo $productPartCode; ?></p>
    <p class="product-price-mobile visible-xs">£<?php echo $showPrice; ?></p>
    <form method="post" class="add-to-basket-submit" action="extras.php?site=<?php echo $_SESSION['basketSiteNo']; ?>&action=add&code=<?php echo $productPartCode; ?>">
      <input class="add-to-basket-qty" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2"/>
      <input class="add-to-basket-description" type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $productDescription; ?>"  style="display:none;" />
      <input class="add-to-basket-price" type="number" name="price" value="<?php echo $showPrice; ?>"  style="display:none;" />
      <input class="add-to-basket-img" type="text" name="img" value="<?php echo $productImage; ?>"  style="display:none;" />
      <input class="add-to-basket-thumb" type="text" name="thumb" value="<?php echo $productThumb; ?>"  style="display:none;" />
      <button class="add-to-basket-button" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon text-tw-red glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></button>
    </form>
</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#myDataTable').dataTable({
 "fnDrawCallback": function() {                  
   $(".add-to-basket-submit").on('submit', function() {
     var item = $(this).parent().attr('id');
     var action = $(this).attr('action');
     var quantity = parseInt($(this).children('.add-to-basket-qty').val());
     var description = $(this).children('.add-to-basket-description').val();
     var price = Number($(this).children('.add-to-basket-price').val());
     var img = $(this).children('.add-to-basket-img').val();
     var thumb = $(this).children('.add-to-basket-thumb').val();
     $.post(action, { quantity: quantity, description: description, price: price, img: img, thumb: thumb } );
     var numberOfItemsInBasket = parseInt($('.number-of-items-in-basket').html());
     var totalOfBasket = Number($('#total-of-basket').html());
     numberOfItemsInBasket = numberOfItemsInBasket + 1;
     $('.number-of-items-in-basket').html(numberOfItemsInBasket);
     totalOfBasket = totalOfBasket + (quantity*price);
     totalOfBasket = totalOfBasket.toFixed(2);
     $('#total-of-basket').html(totalOfBasket);
     $('#' + item).find('form').hide();
     $('#' + item).append('<div class="in-basket-info">in basket</div>');
     return false;
   });
 }
});
```

Similar problem was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186700/jquery-datatables-fndrawcallback-recursive-issue).

In my case using .on did not help. 
I've also tried to place the function in initComplete, but this only works when tables is drawn first time, and not after table is redrawn.

Please help.

Comment: That's the exact intention of fnDrawCallback: being called every time the table is redrawn. You should try to add the event listener outside such callback.
btw, what version of datatables are you using? that's the deprecated syntax, if you're using 1.10 onwards I'd recommend giving the new syntax a try.

Comment: Thanks Sebastianb. I think I did what you said and now all works. I've placed .on submit function above whole dataTable function. I'm using 1.10.12.

Comment: @Andrewski , it could be nice to post your solution as answer for other persons who search, how to figure it out.